# Ruby how to increment a string number

Tags: ruby

How can I confidently increment a string number in Ruby? I understand I can call `"1".next` and produce `"2"` but this does not work for negative numbers.

```
"-3".next
=> "-4"
```

How can I call to increment both positive and negative string digits? I want to return value as String.

Comment: You could roundtrip through a number: `x.to_i.next.to_s`

Comment: It's not interpreted as a negative number. More like `"chapter-3"`

Comment: The *really correct* way to do this is to figure out why you have a "string number" and not a number in the first place, and fix that problem, instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: @Jörg, I expect the *really correct* approach is to back up one more step and avoid incrementing the string representations of numbers that are mixed in with other text. Maybe we're saying the same thing: change the design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert that string to integer, call `#next` and then convert it back to string

```rb
'-3'.to_i.next.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do `("-3".to_i + 1).to_s` but that does not account for float values (if you cared for that). You can call `gsub` with a block and match with regex to convert and increment. `next` does not work for negatives as it only evaluates the rightmost numeric and pays no attention to the minus character. The below matches for integers or floats and increments them based on the integer type:

```
INCREMENTAL = 1

def increment_str(str)
  str.gsub(/(-)?\d+(.\d+)?/) { |x| x.include?(".") ? x.to_f + INCREMENTAL : x.to_i + INCREMENTAL }
end

increment_str("-3") => "-2"
increment_str("3") => "4"
increment_str("-3.0") => "-2.0"
increment_str("3.0") => "4.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer depends on whether the input is integer or float. In each case, cast it to the appropriate numeric type (`to_i` to `to_f`), increment by 1, and cast back to string. For example:

```
['-1.23', '-1', '0', '1', '1.23'].each do |str|
  int_str_plus_1 = (str.to_i + 1).to_s
  float_str_plus_1 = (str.to_f + 1).to_s
  puts [str, int_str_plus_1, float_str_plus_1].join("\t")
end
```

Prints:

```
-1.23  0  -0.22999999999999998
-1     0  0.0
0      1  1.0
1      2  2.0
1.23   2  2.23
```